# passing Curl parameter as a parameter

Tags: php, date, curl

I have a curl function that requests data on Asteroids and get backs results. Currently I am just hard coding in the date parameters for the result, I would like the user to be able to enter their selected dates and get the result how could I add this, I am new to using Curl and keep hitting a wall, the code so far is below,

```
<?php
session_start();
// Method: POST, PUT, GET etc
// Data: array("param" => "value") ==> index.php?param=value

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method) {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die(curl_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
$params = array(
    'start_date' => '01/03/2016',
    'end_date' => '02/03/2016',
    'api_key' => 'demo key'
);
$data   = json_decode(callAPI('GET', 'https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed', $params));

//var_dump($data);

echo "<h1>Near-Earth Object (NEO) Report between " . $params['start_date'] . " and " . $params['end_date'] . "</h1>";

foreach ($data->near_earth_objects as $date => $count) {
    echo "<p>" . sizeof($count) . " objects detected on $date</p>";

    echo "<ol>";
    foreach ($data->near_earth_objects->$date as $near_earth_object) {
        echo "<li>" . $near_earth_object->name . " <a href='" . $near_earth_object->nasa_jpl_url . "'>" . $near_earth_object->nasa_jpl_url . "</a><br>";
        echo "Estimated Diameter: " . $near_earth_object->estimated_diameter->meters->estimated_diameter_min . "-" . $near_earth_object->estimated_diameter->meters->estimated_diameter_max . " metres<br>";

        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($near_earth_object->close_approach_data as $close_approach) {
            echo "<li>Close approach on " . $close_approach->close_approach_date . " velocity " . $close_approach->relative_velocity->kilometers_per_hour . " km/h " . "missing " . $close_approach->orbiting_body . " by " . $close_approach->miss_distance->kilometers . " km</li> ";
        }
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
    echo "</ol>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. I modified your code slightly. The date format you had was also incorrect. You were providing the format `mm/dd/yyyy` when the API calls for a [format](https://api.nasa.gov/api.html#NeoWS) of `yyyy-mm-dd` (notice the year goes in front and you need hyphens instead of slashes).

I used GET values for the start and end date (note the API only allows [7 days](https://api.nasa.gov/api.html#NeoWS) between the start and end dates). So you can change the date by adding `?start=2015-05-01&end=2015-05-05` to the end of the URL you use to access this code (it could also be implemented as a GET-method form):

```php
<?php
session_start();
// Method: POST, PUT, GET etc
// Data: array("param" => "value") ==> index.php?param=value

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method) {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die(curl_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}

$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : date('Y-m-d')));
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(isset($_GET['end']) ? $_GET['end'] : date('Y-m-d')));

if( !$startDate ) {
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d');
}

if( !$endDate ) {
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d');
}

$params = array(
    'start_date' => $startDate,
    'end_date' => $endDate,
    'api_key' => 'NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo'
);

$data = json_decode(callAPI('GET', 'https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed', $params));

echo "<h1>Near-Earth Object (NEO) Report between " . $params['start_date'] . " and " . $params['end_date'] . "</h1>";

foreach ($data->near_earth_objects as $date => $count) {
    echo "<p>" . sizeof($count) . " objects detected on $date</p>";

    echo "<ol>";
    foreach ($data->near_earth_objects->$date as $near_earth_object) {
        echo "<li>" . $near_earth_object->name . " <a href='" . $near_earth_object->nasa_jpl_url . "'>" . $near_earth_object->nasa_jpl_url . "</a><br>";
        echo "Estimated Diameter: " . $near_earth_object->estimated_diameter->meters->estimated_diameter_min . "-" . $near_earth_object->estimated_diameter->meters->estimated_diameter_max . " metres<br>";

        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($near_earth_object->close_approach_data as $close_approach) {
            echo "<li>Close approach on " . $close_approach->close_approach_date . " velocity " . $close_approach->relative_velocity->kilometers_per_hour . " km/h " . "missing " . $close_approach->orbiting_body . " by " . $close_approach->miss_distance->kilometers . " km</li> ";
        }
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
    echo "</ol>";
}
```

The dates can be entered in any format that strtotime understands. In the event of an invalid date it will default to todays date. If the API throws an error (like when the date range is larger than 7 days), it will just throw an error. You may want to add some error detection.

Comment: HI Jim Thanks for the help, was really stuck on it, If I want the user to be able to input dates on the page would the GET method be something like this    <form action= "" method = "GET">
        <div class="form-field">
  <input type="type" name="startDate"  placeholder= "Enter your Start Date" value="<?php $startDate; ?>"/>
  
  
  </div>
      </form>

Comment: The input `name="startDate"` would be `name="start"` unless you alter the code to use startDate instead.

Comment: HI Jim I wonder could you help me further, I have added a function to allow user to input the start date and I added code to set the end date to 7days after, but the page will load before user has even added the date can you help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need help with. Since it is something separate I would say open another question otherwise you would probably be violating the site's TOS. You can link it here and I will take a look. The page would need to load prior to the user selecting the date. The code I provided uses the current date if no date is given by the user (like when they first load the page).

Comment: HI Jim, Yeah it is a follow on from the code you provided, I have used the code for a page where the user will enter a date and be provided with results. I want the results only to be shown if a date is input, currently the page when loading will already have todays results showing,  I will open up another question and link it over give me 2 mins

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128676/using-date-vairables-in-an-api